# set shipping cost by heaviest product @ CE 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, ce-1.9.2.0

we use a product-configurator for some products. There you can set the height  and weight of pvc-banners. Now is the problem to calculate the shipping cost by the length. The configurator set the "short site" from the pvc-banners at row-weight @ sales_flat_quote_item. thats fine!

now its the problem for me to set the shippingcost by the "heaviest" or better by the longest product.

if i have one product in the cart the shipping cost corect. if i edit the quantity - it`s fine - i modified some files for this.

If i have more than 1 product in the cart the weight1 is add to weight2.

for this i have add a module - but since last update it dosn`t work.

more details:

../app/code/local/Mage/Bannership/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Bannership>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Mage_Bannership>
    </modules>
    <global>       
        <models>
            <bannership>
                <class>Mage_Bannership_Model</class>               
            </bannership> 
            <core> 
                <rewrite>
                    <shipping>
                        Mage_Bannership_Model_Shipping
                    </shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </core>          
        </models>       
    </global>   
</config>
```

../app/code/local/Mage/Bannership/Model/Shipping.php:

```
class Mage_Bannership_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping {

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
        $maxWeight = 0;
        foreach($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $maxWeight = max($maxWeight, $item->getRowWeight());
        }
        $request->setPackageWeight($maxWeight);

        return parent::collectRates($request);
    }
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mage_Bannership>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </Mage_Bannership>
</modules>
<global>       
    <models>
        <bannership>
            <class>Mage_Bannership_Model</class>               
        </bannership> 
        <shipping> 
            <rewrite>
                <shipping>
                    Mage_Bannership_Model_Shipping
                </shipping>
            </rewrite>
        </shipping>          
    </models>       
</global>
```

Comment: The row-weight from the quote-items are okay in db. but the total weight of the cart iss add by the row-weight from each item.

Comment: i want to set the total weight(cart) by the highest row-weight from all item in cart. Is "setPackageWeight" the right "function"?

Comment: Yes, this is right function.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to fix it.

... we use the Matrixrate - Free Version from Webshopapps - this extension override the other module. So i add some lines code at: 
/app/code/community/Webshopapps/Matrixrate/Model/Carrier/Matrixrate.php:

~ line 111

// heaviest weight set shipping price - MOD
// weight is override by lenght ...

```
$maxWeight = 0;
if ($request->getAllItems()) {
    foreach($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $maxWeight = max($maxWeight, $item->getRowWeight());
    }
$request->setPackageWeight($maxWeight);
}
```